# Django get subobjects in view

Tags: python, django

My two models:

```py
class BusinessType(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Business(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    bus_type = models.ForeignKey(BusinessType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, name="type")

class Appointment(models.Model):
    from datetime import datetime

    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE, name="appointments")
    done = False

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Now I add this context to my view:

```py
'business':Business.objects.order_by('name'),
```

My template:

```
{{business|length}}<hr />
    {%for business_entry in business%}
        {{business_entry.appointments.all|length}}
    {%endfor%}
```

Now the business length outputs "2" and that's right, I have two business objects.

But for the appointments I get the value "0" which is not true.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `related_name="appointments"`, not `name="appointments"`.

So, change:

```
business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE, name="appointments")
```

To:

```
business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="appointments")
```

---

You might want to read: [ForeignKey.related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)